# Flatten product of two dictionary lists

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have two lists of dictionaries which I am trying to get the product of:

```
from itertools import product 


list1 = [{'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 2}]
list2 = [{'C': 1, 'D': 1}, {'C': 1, 'D': 2}]

for p in product(list1, list2):
    print p
```

and this gives me the output:

```
({'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'C': 1, 'D': 1})
({'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'C': 1, 'D': 2})
({'A': 2, 'B': 2}, {'C': 1, 'D': 1})
({'A': 2, 'B': 2}, {'C': 1, 'D': 2})
({'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'C': 1, 'D': 1})
({'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'C': 1, 'D': 2})
({'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'C': 1, 'D': 1})
({'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'C': 1, 'D': 2})
```

How would I flatten these so the output is a single dict rather than a tuple of dicts?:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 2}
{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 2}
{'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
{'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 2}
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to merge the dictionaries

```
 for p1, p2 in product(list1, list2):
     merged = {**p1, **p2}
     print(merged)
```

In earlier versions of Python, you can't merge with this expression. Use `p1.update(p2)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using python 2.7 so i tried `p1.merge(p2)` but this gave me: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'merge'`

Comment: @Michael: sorry, i meant `update()` not `merge*()`